# Predicting digits in multiplication result

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we have two positive integers *a* and *b*. What would we know about the digits of the multiplication result of a and b without actually multiplying *a* and *b*?

For example, would we know if there is a 0 in the multiplication result of *a* and *b*?

Comment: We can find lots of digits of the product but no info about **all  digits**. For example the question about existence of $0$ is hopeless. The reason: take two huge numbers $a,b$ such that $ab$ has a 0. Then by changing one digit of $a$ somewhere in the middle you will get $a'b$ without zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for the note! What is the info we can find out about the product? Is there a link to where I can learn more?